# Freetextbox is not declared

Tags: asp.net, freetextbox

My code says that the freetextbox (ID is txtQuestion) is not declared (shown below)

[image]

But I have the complete configuration in my `web.config`

[image]

And in the .aspx file

[image]

And I already installed it.

[image]

Before I transfer all these files into the server, it works well but when transfer these files into a server (and I edit the codes from a remote PC connected to the server), it has this error. Can anyone help me? The installation of freetextbox is its assembly configurations only right?

Comment: Do you have actual control in your ASPX file (not just `register` refefence) ?

Comment: You mean like this? `<FTB:FreeTextBox id="txtQuestion" runat="Server" ButtonSet="OfficeXP" DownLevelMessage="" EnableHtmlMode="False" FormatHtmlTagsToXhtml="False" GutterBackColor="224, 224, 224" Height="100px" ToolbarBackColor="LightGray" ToolbarLayout="Bold,Italic,Underline" ToolbarStyleConfiguration="NotSet" Focus="True" ButtonImagesLocation="InternalResource" ScriptMode="External" SslUrl="./" />`. It says that element Freetextbox is an unknown element.

Comment: I just think that may be freetextbox is not working in a production server yet will only work in a "localhost-based".

Comment: It should work everywhere - when you uploaded project to the remote server - did u also upload FreeTextBox.dll into the Bin folder?

Comment: Yes sir as shown in the last image above. What I observe is that when I run the local version I have in my PC, it works well. But when I try to run the server-side version, it has errors so I assume that freetextbox will only work locally.

Comment: Do other pages of your site (ones that do not havetheFreeTextBox) load normally? Also, try removing reference from Web.Config, let's see if it loads directly from Bin.

Comment: It loads normally. I use freetextbox to insert data into my database. I already tried it but it still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to the Application Pool settings.

**Process Model - Load User Profile = True**

**Rapid-Fail Protection - Enabled = False**

**Recycling - Regular Time Interval (minutes) = 0**

One or some of the above solved the problem.

Of course you should check **General - .NET Framework Version**